# Android SDK (Eclipse) : How To Use SetOnKeyListener with Button?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button

I just don't know how to do it. The Code is so confusing for me. Can anyone please show me the code with explanation?

What I want is to assign enter keyCode to the `btn` button, so when user touches *Enter SoftKey*, the toast will show up just like clicking the button!

**Here is The Simple App to use the code :**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);


  b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


@Override

public void onClick(View v) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

    });

}

@Override

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

    }
```

**Please Explain it to me don't Just Write it , I'm New to Android , thanks for your Time**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need to set `OnKeyListener` for your button similar way you already set `OnClickListener`:

```
b.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // your custom implementation
        if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER == keyCode) { // match ENTER key            {
            // show the toast
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello World",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true; // indicate that we handled event, won't propagate it
        }
        return false; // when we don't handle other keys, propagate event further
    }
});
```

Additional explanations are in the comments. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for Answering , I have another question , I have an app that I want to use OnKeyListener on a specific button , but the button has a way long code and it still gives me errors , can you please tell me how to achieve it ? @kiruwka

Comment: Well, I recommend you try the code above on newly created simple button and verify it works as you expect. Then if you need to modify existing button, you could update your question or create a new question providing all the details (button code, error logs you have, what you tried)

Comment: I tried it on Emulator and it stopped working on startup idk why :(

Comment: The code I posted works fine on a new button(just confirmed it myself). You probably have some other issues. Try examining your `logcat` output for the details of the runtime errors you have.

Comment: @ kiruwka : The Problem is I'm totally new to Android , i'm Learning since a week only , I know how to use Log cat but not really familiar with it , by the way here is my other app code please check it , I know it's Long :[link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297031/android-sdk-eclipse-typing-game-how-to-create-an-array-of-string-resources) –  Souls Reaper